# What is meaning of ' character?

Tags: octave

In this formula :

```
theta = theta .- alpha * (1/m) * (((X*theta) - y)' * X)';
```

What is significance of character `'` ?

Searches for 'prime character octave' and ' ' character octave' does not yield any results.

Comment: From [some documentation I found by googling "Octave syntax"](http://math.jacobs-university.de/oliver/teaching/iub/resources/octave/octave-intro/octave-intro.html) - "`A'` transposes and conjugates `A`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is 'single quote'.

I don't know anything about octave, but [these docs](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/octave/octave_4.html) indicate that it's used as a transpose operator.

> x'
>   Complex conjugate transpose. For real arguments, this operator is the same as the transpose operator. For complex arguments, this operator is equivalent to the expression `conj (x.')`
>
> x.'
>   Transpose.